Minimum value of overlapping rasters while maintaining the source file name
I have around 15 raster files that are based on the depth values of geological formations. I have created a "mosaic to new raster" with a "mosaic operator" of "minimum" which gives me the minimum value at each raster cell location.
Now I also want to create a feature layer from this that displays which formations are the deepest at each raster cell. Basically a layer I can visualize that shows at each cell location what was the source raster for this minimum value.
I have tried a number of things with union, dissolve and merge but none of the results give me what I am looking for.

You could generate an bitwise-or Con() cascade to bitmask the lowest value into each cell, setting 1 for raster1, 2 for raster2, 4 for raster3,..., and then if the value is 6, you know the minimum value in that cell was contributed by both raster2 and raster3.

Convert it output to raster of 1. Use it to sample other 15. In output table find column number with minimum. Associate this numbers with raster names
